# can't access backend while frontend works perfect

Tags: wp-admin, automatic-updates

Before 2 days there was a automatic update for wordpress, which I for my website.

When the update was over, I tried to access backend but I always get this message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_is_mobile() in /home/*******/public_html/wp-login.php on line 67
```

Can you give me any idea what to do, how to fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/!\ **Before change I suggest, please make a full backup (code + database) of your Wordpress.**

- Deactivate all plugins.

If it does not help try next

- Re-upload all files and folders (**except the wp-content folder**) from a fresh download of WordPress.

Comment: Thanks for help @Maxim Orlovsky. I have re-uploaded all file (except wp-content) and when I try to log in admin I get following error: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method wpdb::delete() in /home/********/public_html/wp-includes/option.php on line 370

Comment: Delete folder `wp-includes` and upload it again from a fresh Wordpress. Make sure all files successfully uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You're not the first one to get this error. Similar problems have been reported [here](http://onlineinfoden.com/undefined-function-wp_is_mobile-how-i-resolved-this-wp-issue/) and on [Wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-errorcall-to-undefined-function-wp_is_mobile)

And the answer from the Wordpress.org link is:

> Try:
>   - switching to the Twenty Eleven theme by renaming your current theme's folder inside wp-content/themes and adding "-old" to the end
>   of the folder name using FTP or whatever file management application
>   your host provides.
>
> - resetting the plugins folder by FTP or phpMyAdmin.
> - re-uploading all files & folders - except the wp-content folder - from a fresh download of WordPress.
> - running the upgrade manually via wp-admin/upgrade.php

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that the automatic update process wasn't successful (even though, WordPress might have showed you a different message).

As Maxim already mentioned, I'd recommend to re-install WordPress manually.